# How to link specific array item to a field in a form?

Tags: arrays, database, vue.js

I have a form with a field titled 'Desserts'. The desserts are in an array:

```
data: () => ({
    newDesserts: [
        {id: 6, name: 'Coca Cola',
        {id: 1, name: 'Apple'},
        {id: 17, name: 'Cake',
    ],
}),
```

The form field looks like this:

```
v-text-field 
    outlined
></v-text-field>
```

How can I link the array item with id 17 to this form field? I've tried using

```
v-text-field 
    outlined
    v-model="newDessert[17].data"
></v-text-field>
```

Where 'data' represents the column I want to add it to in the DB. However, it hasn't worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the index of the array to access it.

You can search for an index with `findIndex`.

```html
<v-text-field outlined v-model="newDessert[newDessert.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 17)].name"/>
```

Comment: While this answer does work for this specific case, I really don't see the practicality of it due to the object's id being hard coded directly into the template..

Comment: Though I do agree that hardcoding it directly onto the template is generally not a good idea and takes up space, for this particular case they have to be in a specific order, style and some have different components e.g. one dessert belongs to a v-text-field and one to a v-textarea. If there was a better way I would love to try it!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want all the desserts listed, rather than hardcoding array indexes into your template. If this is the case, your code would become:

```
<v-text-field 
  outlined
  v-for="(item, index) in newDesserts"
  :key="index"
  v-model="item.name"
></v-text-field>
```